# Creating basic navigation in File Maker

Tags: filemaker

I'm new to File Maker and looking to do what I assume is a relatively straightforward task. I have a table of `Users` and a table of `Tasks`. Each user can have multiple tasks associated with him/her but every task can have only one user.

From the list view of `Users` I want to be able to click on any given person and then see a list of all their assigned `tasks`. What is best practice for creating this kind of filtered list view?

My current best guess is to have a script that navigates a user from the `Users` layout to the `Tasks` layout. This script would also set a global field (`selected User ID`) based on which record the script was executed from (i.e. if i clicked on “Paul” it would set the `selected meeting ID` to his ID). I would then filter the `tasks` layout by the global `selected User ID` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileMaker has a specific script step for just this kind of thing. It's "Go to Related Record".
It does exactly what you need, including going to the relevant layout in an optional new window and filtering records. No need for any additional logic.

As a side note, a portal to this relationship on the form view layout will display the user's related records in the portal as a list. You can attach a button on a portal row to go to this specific record, using the same script step I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

You can open a pop-up window or a card showing an external table which lists all tasks of the corresponding user you clicked on. A field can act as a button and launch a unique action or a script for multiple actions. Don't forget a close button to go back to the list of users.

Comment: Not very explicit in terms of the steps and code associated.

Comment: It's difficult to expose what is in the design of layouts and what is part of the basement of FileMaker. The design of the database is a part of the solution with a relation between users and tasks, this relationship permits use of an external table. The use of a field as a button on a layout is a basic element of Filemaker. 95% of the answer is in the design of the database and FileMaker gives as extra multiple solutions that use main and external table.

Comment: Here an example of database : [users and tasks](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyrl3t0442xqac6/Users%20and%20tasks.fmp12.zip?dl=0)